# FormData.append("key", "value") is not working

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

Can you tell me whats wrong with this:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("key", "value");
console.log(formdata);
```

My output looks like this, I cant find my "key" - "value" pair

```
FormData
*__proto__: FormData
**append: function append() { [native code] }
***arguments: null
***caller: null
***length: 0
***name: "append"
***prototype: append
***__proto__: function Empty() {}
*constructor: function FormData() { [native code] }
**arguments: null
**caller: null
**length: 0
**name: "FormData"
**prototype: FormData
**toString: function toString() { [native code] }
*__proto__: Object
**__proto__: Object
**__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
**__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
**__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
**__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
**constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
**hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
**isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
**propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
**toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
**toString: function toString() { [native code] }
**valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
```

I can't understand! Yesterday it worked so well, and today my head crashed the keyboard so many times! Firefox, Chrome, both the same :/

Answer (score 140, accepted):

**New in Chrome 50+ and Firefox 39+ (resp. 44+):**

- `formdata.entries()` (combine with `Array.from()` for debugability)
- `formdata.get(key)`
- and more very useful methods

**Original answer:**

What I usually do to 'debug' a `FormData` object, is just send it (anywhere!) and check the browser logs (eg. Chrome devtools' Network tab).

You don't need a/the same Ajax framework. You don't need any details. Just send it:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
xhr.send(data);
```

Easy.

Comment: thanks - this was a useful quick way to get the FormData object by typing it into the Chrome console.

Comment: [According to Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/formdata-methods-for-inspection-and-modification?hl=en) formData methods were added in Chrome v50.

Comment: How would you look at the browser logs if its a mobile browser like Safari?  I am using  the FormData object in a web app meant for mobile and can't figure out how to debug it.

Comment: @kiwicomb123 `Formdata.entries()` + `Array.from()` + `alert()` if it's modern enough, or look into [mobile debugging](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787)

Comment: so no edge or ie11?

Comment: Was curious about the plain/pure-js answer!

Answer (score 50):

You say it's not working. What are you expecting to happen?

<del>There's no way of getting the data out of a `FormData` object; it's just intended for you to use to send data along with an `XMLHttpRequest` object (for the `send` method).</del>

Update almost five years later: In some newer browsers, this is no longer true and you can now see the data provided to `FormData` in addition to just stuffing data into it. [See the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092429/573976) for more info.

Comment: OK... this sucks. Why can I not log the FormData in my console? :-( This just makes no sense to me, since i thought it is an common object

Comment: @netzaffin: Both Firebug and Chrome's inspector let you see the sent request parameters in an XHR request as long as you've opened the network tab and started logging, so you should be able to get by on that. You could also make a wrapper object that logs the fields and appends to the FormData, and then check that for the values (not forgetting to send the inner FormData instead of the wrapper object).

Comment: At least, can I check if `formdata` object has a file inside?

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa: It doesn't seem like you can get any information out of it. You'll just have to keep this information yourself.

Comment: As pointed out by @Jesper you can check the XHR request sent in the network tab tab of Developer tools , there is Params option there which even lets you see the content of POST request sent. Also the response.

Comment: @netzaffin if you want a common object, then you can [loop through the entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) in formData to build your object. Keep in mind the minimum browser requirements though.

Comment: Yes there is: `Array.from(new FormData(event.target));` will give you a 2d array of key value pairs.

Answer (score 31):

You might have been having the same problem I was initially having. I was trying to use FormData to grab all my input files to upload an image, but at the same time I wanted to append a session ID to the information passed along to the server. All this time, I thought by appending the information, you would be able to see it in the server by accessing the object. I was wrong. When you append to FormData, the way to check the appended information on the server is by a simple `$_POST['*your appended data*']` query. like so:

js:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var sessionID = 8;
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append('id', sessionID);

    $.ajax({
        url: "yoururl.php",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

then on php:

```
$sessionID = $_POST['id'];
$files = $_FILES['image'];

$foreach ($files as $key=>val){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

If you are in Chrome you can check the Post Data

Here is How to check the Post data

1. Go to Network Tab
2. Look for the Link to which you are sending Post Data
3. Click on it
4. In the Headers, you can check Request Payload to check the post data

[image: Chrome's DevTools]

Answer (score 12):

> form data doesn't appear in web browser console

```
for (var data of formData) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

try this way it will show

Answer (score 8):

you can see it 
you need to use `console.log(formData.getAll('your key'))`;
watch the 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll

Answer (score 3):

In my case on Edge browser:

```
  const formData = new FormData(this.form);
  for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      formObject[key] = value;
  }
```

give me the same error

So I'm not using `FormData` and i just manually build an object

```
import React from 'react';    
import formDataToObject from 'form-data-to-object';

  ...

let formObject = {};

// EDGE compatibility -  replace FormData by
for (let i = 0; i < this.form.length; i++) {
  if (this.form[i].name) {
    formObject[this.form[i].name] = this.form[i].value;
  }
}

const data = formDataToObject.toObj(formObject): // convert "user[email]":"customer@mail.com" => "user":{"email":"customer@mail.com"}

const orderRes = await fetch(`/api/orders`, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });

const order = await orderRes.json();
```

Answer (score 2):

## React Version

Make sure to have a header with `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`

```
_handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', this.state.file);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }

     axios.post("/upload", formData, config)
         .then((resp) => {
             console.log(resp)
         }).catch((error) => {
    })
  }

  _handleImageChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    this.setState({
      file: file
    });
  }
```

### View

```
  #html
 <input className="form-control"
    type="file" 
    onChange={(e)=>this._handleImageChange(e)} 
 />
```