# FormData() XHR2

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use FormData(). I have tried this code in Multiple versions of Chrome and Firefox.

```
var fData = new FormData();
fData.append('foo', 'bar');
console.log('formData', fData);
```

fData, when logged, only gives me the created object with a prototype of FormData and no additional "foo" value. There are no errors, it just seems to fail silently.

I have also tried

```
var fData = new FormData(formElement);
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @aganders3 Not yet. I'll post it here if I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing a bit of research, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752188/formdata-appendkey-value-is-not-working) which says you can't get your data directly from the `FormData` object. However, you can see what data is sent if you examine the `XMLHttpRequest` object after sending it. This allowed me to see what I was sending (I used the network tab of Chrome's inspector) and effectively debug my code.

So to answer your question: it is probably working already, you just can't see your data in the `FormData` object.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It ended up that I wasn't receiving multipart/form-data on the server. Since I'm using node.js I had to use Formidable to receive the request.

Comment: How do you see the request data in the XMLHttpRequest object?  It seems like there isn't a property for security reasons.