# How can i get data from FormData in javascript?

Tags: javascript, qunit, form-data

I need to read data from FormData? I try to read something like `someFormatData["valueName"]` but it not working.
`options["fileId"]` or `options["file"]` does not work. Also I try `options.fileId` same result:

```
function upload(file, fileId, callback) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("fileID", fileId);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}


asyncTest("test upload chunk", function() {
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello world!"], { type: "text/plain" }),        
        options = null,
        fileID ="someFileID",
        response;

    jQuery.ajax = function(param) {
        options = param;   // THIS is FormData object 
        // how to read fileId and file from here
    };

    upload(blob, fileID, function (data) {
        response = data;  
    });

    options.success({
        someProp: 'responseFromServer'
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        QUnit.equal(options, "dataTosend", "parameters is OK");
        QUnit.equal(response["someProp"], "responseFromServer", "Response ok");
        start();
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752188/formdata-appendkey-value-is-not-working

Comment: Is param the FormData object, or param.data ? From the doc at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData, I don't think there is a way to access the data. However, unless you're testing $.ajax, you might want to spy on FormData to check that you called append with the right ids...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take your `FormData` object you can use a few different methods on it… What you are looking for is

```js
formData.get()
```

or

```js
formData.getAll()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Note that the `get()` method is not fully supported on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinNabialek been a long day and forgot the markup!

Comment: get() does not, getAll() is supported by Chrome

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yes, I saw it on that page, but both methods aren't work in my Chrome (v40)

Comment: see at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get. it says that chrome, IE and safari dont support those methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can read using this

```
formData.get('fileId') // to read Id
formData.get('file') // to read the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to list all entries of a FormData :

```
for(const entry of formData){
  console.log(entry); // Array: ['entryName', 'entryValue']
}
```