# Getting data using formdata?

Tags: javascript

Here's my form:

```
    <form id="content-add-form" role="form" name="content-add-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I'm trying to get form data using:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#content-add-form'));
```

But it's not working, any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var formData = new FormData($('#content-add-form')[0]);
```

You need to pass the actual form element - not the jQuery object containing it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

> **Constructor**
>
> new FormData (optional HTMLFormElement form)

As for why you can't see the data, read here: [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TGzRa/

Comment: Actually, this still does not work. I can now get out anything I append to form data, but not the data I intialize it with.

Comment: @panthro Well, it will always be a snapshot of the form in its current state.

Comment: Yes, I have fillied in data, nothing is coming through

Comment: @panthro My test is working fine. See the update. I think your problem lies elsewhere