# Why is FormData empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, form-data

I have followed [this guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

```
var formData = new FormData();    
formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456);
console.log(formData);
```

Why is `formData` empty?

Comment: Please check. This gives value.

Comment: What makes you think it's empty? It works in a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/y9yd6okn/

Comment: [There's no way to inspect/console.log it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Their is way to access FormData

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456);

console.log(formData.get("username"));
console.log(formData.get("accountnum"));
```

Comment: Note that `FormData.get()` only works in Firefox and Opera.

Comment: Are you sure? I get `Uncaught TypeError: formData.get is not a function` when I run it in Chrome 47: http://jsfiddle.net/pLyhnkw5/. Also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) says that this has no support in Chrome.

Comment: Yes correct FormData() works but get function not working.