# FormData append - not working

Tags: javascript

Why my code not working ?

```
var myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append('xxx',1233);
console.log(myFormData);
```

Why myFormData is empty?

https://repl.it/B8K4

Answer (score -1):

You cant log it or get data from it in a simple way.

Already explained here: [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

Comment: Ahh, Thank you. You saved my morning