# Appending form inputs to Formdata Object not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file

I have a form which is for sending mails.It contain fields such as **`to_name,subject,message and attachment button`**.I will create a file input field on clicking the button with class `.file_add_btn`.

```
//click event for add files
$(".file_add_btn").click(function(){
    if($("#file_div").html() == '')
    {
       $("#file_div").append('<div class="file_btn_div" id="file_btn_div_first"><input type="file" class="btn_browse" name="file_uploads[]">'+
       '<input type="button" class="del_file" value="X"></div>'); 
    }
    else
    {
        if($(document).find('.btn_browse:last').get(0).files.length !==0)
        {
            $("#file_div").append('<div class="file_btn_div"><input type="file" class="btn_browse" name="file_uploads[]">'+
            '<input type="button" class="del_file" value="X"></div>');
        }
    }

});
```

I write the following function to include file inputs into formData.

```
$.fn.serializefiles = function() {
    var obj = $(this);

    var form_data = new FormData(this[0]);
    $.each($(obj).find('.btn_browse'), function(i, tag) {
        $.each(tag.files, function(i, file) {
             console.log(tag.name+' '+file.name)//this is printing in console
                form_data.append(tag.name, file);
        });
    });
    var params = $(obj).serializeArray();
    $.each(params, function (i, val) {
            console.log(val.name+'<br/>');
            console.log(val.value+'<br/>');
            **//here file names are not coming.All other elements are coming.They are not adding to form_data object**
            form_data.append(val.name, val.value);
    });
    return form_data;
};
```

My ajax call is like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: 'process.php',
    data: $("#compose_message").serializefiles() ,//formID=#compose_message
    asyn: true,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success:function()
          ....
```

I am not able to append the  inputs into the `form_data`  object.In console,I see `[object FormData]` inside the POST on button click.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need this `serializefiles` function, when you should be able to simply do `data: new FormData($("#compose_message")[0])`?

Comment: If we do `data: new FormData($("#compose_message")[0])`,how can I append the multiple file inputs and other formdatas@Mikey

Comment: @Mikey I have used `console.log(JSON.stringify(new FormData($("#compose_message")[0])));`,this is giving me empty value `{}` in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** My initial comment above was correct. You don't need to do anything fancy except pass the form object into `FormData` constructor as shown in my example below.

`console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));` will never show the values of the `FormData`. However, if you look in your browser's network tab, the request that gets sent will show the values being passed.

If you want to check the data before it is being passed, you could use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293779/1022914).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>
        input {
            float: left;
            clear: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="text" value="text">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="hidden">
        <input type="file" name="file_uploads[]" value="">
        <input type="file" name="file_uploads[]" value="">
        <input type="file" name="file_uploads[]" value="">
        <input type="button" value="Add">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(formData)); // will always be {}

            $.ajax({ url: '404', type: 'post', data: formData, processData: false, contentType: false });
        });

        $('[type=button]').on('click', function () {
            $(this).before('<input type="file" name="file_uploads[]" value="">');
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have checked the result using `console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));` after copying your code,but it gives me `{}`.What can be the reason my bro

Comment: That's because you can't print the contents of `FormData` that way. I edited my answer with a quick example and tested it locally.

Comment: I have used this code but in my `process.php`,its giving me `Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Invalid parameters.` since I used `if (
                        !isset($_FILES['file_uploads']['error']) ||
                        is_array($_FILES['file_uploads']['error'])
                    ) {
                        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
                    }`

Comment: If you examine your `$_FILES` array, using `print_r`, it should be similar to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240) where every value is an array. When you use this AJAX approach of submitting files, I think there will always be arrays. You need to loop through each file and do the necessary checking (and by minimum using [is_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)).

Comment: The `$_FILES` is empty array for me:(

Comment: I am using same code with a sample script and it works :/ I got some time to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) if you want.

Comment: If you can I can give my teamviewer..so that you can check.plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113532/discussion-between-mikey-and-techy).

Answer (score 1):

specify exact data for formdata

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('section', 'general');
formData.append('action', 'previewImg');
// Main magic with files here
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Ajax request with jquery will looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    // THIS MUST BE DONE FOR FILE UPLOADING
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    // ... Other options like success and etc
})
```

Comment: Should I need to append each form elements seperately.I am doing the same thing inside my function

Comment: I have used `formData.append('section', 'general');` for testing.Then also `console.log(JSON.stringify(new FormData($("#compose_message")[0])));` gives me `{}` string.I think `formData` is not been appended with the values

Answer (score 0):

> **try this**

```
  var form = $("form")[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append('section', 'general');
    formData.append('action', 'previewImg');
    // Main magic with files here
    formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```