# Iterating through FormData in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using FormData to send information back to the server. In some cases however I need to read out the data before I send it.

Chrome allows you to iterate through the collection but IE does not supply the same methods.

The code below works in Chrome:

```
// Create a test FormData object
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key1', 'value1');
formData.append('key2', 'value2');

// Display the key/value pairs
for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx9zgsjn/)

Does anyone know how to achieve the same result in IE? Thanks.

Comment: Use `for...in...` instead of `for...of...` ([Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility))

Comment: The issue is related to the methods on the FormData object, not the use of  `for...of/in...`. IE is missing `formData.keys() / entries()` etc...

Comment: is entries even part of the spec? or a method in ie?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper it's a part of spec. https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-formdata

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a [**`FormData` polyfill**](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData) that works. For details, read [their docs](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData).

## IE 10, IE 11 and Edge

To make it work with IE 10 and above, you'll just have to add a [`WeakMap` polyfill](https://github.com/polygonplanet/weakmap-polyfill) as well.

[**JSBin demo for IE10 and above.**](http://jsbin.com/matubih/edit?html,output)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/weakmap-polyfill/weakmap-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/formdata-polyfill"></script>

<form action="" id="f">
    <input type="text" name="i1" value="v1">
    <input type="text" name="i2" value="v2">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.clear();

    // Create a test FormData object
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('key1', 'value1');
    formData.append('key2', 'value2');

    // Display the key/value pairs
    var formDataEntries = formData.entries(), formDataEntry = formDataEntries.next(), pair;
    while (!formDataEntry.done) {
        pair = formDataEntry.value;
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
        formDataEntry = formDataEntries.next();
    }

    // or, if you are really into compact code
    var es, e, pair;
    for (es = formData.entries(); !(e = es.next()).done && (pair = e.value);) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }

    // testing getting from form
    var myForm = document.getElementById('f');
    for (es = new FormData(myForm).entries(); !(e = es.next()).done && (pair = e.value);) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
</script>
```

<sub>Code above picks up the latest versions. Versions tested: `https://unpkg.com/weakmap-polyfill@2.0.0/weakmap-polyfill.min.js` and `https://unpkg.com/formdata-polyfill@3.0.9/formdata.min.js`</sub>

## IE11 and Edge, only (if you don't have to support IE10):

If you only need IE 11 and above, you can remove the `WeakMap`'s polyfill and just keep `FormData`'s.

[JSBin demo here](http://jsbin.com/medodes/edit?html,output).

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/formdata-polyfill"></script>

<form action="" id="f">
    <input type="text" name="i1" value="v1">
    <input type="text" name="i2" value="v2">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.clear();

    // Create a test FormData object
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('key1', 'value1');
    formData.append('key2', 'value2');

    // Display the key/value pairs
    var formDataEntries = formData.entries(), formDataEntry = formDataEntries.next(), pair;
    while (!formDataEntry.done) {
        pair = formDataEntry.value;
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
        formDataEntry = formDataEntries.next();
    }

    // or, if you are really into compact code
    var es, e, pair;
    for (es = formData.entries(); !(e = es.next()).done && (pair = e.value);) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }

    // testing getting from form element
    const myForm = document.getElementById('f');
    for (es = new FormData(myForm).entries(); !(e = es.next()).done && (pair = e.value);) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
</script>
```

<sub>Code above picks up the latest version. Version tested: `https://unpkg.com/formdata-polyfill@3.0.9/formdata.min.js`</sub>

Comment: Thank you. After days of looking for answers for IE's lack of character, this one worked for me perfectly. Nothing else did.

Comment: It's 2021 and we are still having to use Polyfills to fix InternetExplorer 11 because it's still used by government and banks etc 