# Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, compatibility

I am working with the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, while my code works well on Chrome, Microsoft Edge spits out the following error message `Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'` – which corresponds to the following code:

```
for(let pair of formData.entries()) {
  ...
}
```

I've tried replacing `.entries()` with `.getAll()`, however Microsoft Edge doesn't recognize either of both methods.

Is there a way to get this functionality (iterating over `FormData` files) out of Microsoft Edge?

**FormData Microsoft Edge Console Dump**

[image]

Comment: `entries` and `getAll` are not supported by Edge at this time. Check the Browser compatibility section at the end.

Comment: You will need a polyfill for this, as it isn't supported in Edge. Check here for a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Do you mind posting it as an answer? This will help many people of there getting this error.

Comment: @Agalo MDN docs are shaky `Compatibility unknown; please update this.`

Comment: Why is this tagged `internet-explorer` when it asks about `microsoft-edge`?

Comment: If people are still struggling with this in 2020, then please see the answer to this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079188/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-entries-error-in-ie11

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**2/10/2020 UPDATE:**
Like @Monomachus said, first try adding this line to polyfill.ts:

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
```

If this fixes it, make sure to give his answer credit! If needed, you can manually define it using the instructions below:

---

**Original Response:**
**Essentially, a polyfill is a way you can manually define a function that isn't natively supported on a specific platform/browser.**

In your case, there is a basic definition of the function `Object.entries` given here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill

They provide this simple, ready to deploy definition:

```
if (!Object.entries)
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
  };
```

Looking at the code above, the first thing it checks is if `Object.entries` exists. If it does, no worries, but if it doesn't exist, then it creates it...
As long as this function gets defined before you actually call it in your code, you should be fine.

Using something like [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/), they provide a polyfills.ts file (which gets executed before your app is run) where you can place code like this or import files containing definitions you'll need.

---

**10/30/2018 UPDATE:**

@apsillers correctly pointed out the answer above does not apply to `FormData.entries()`, but to `Object.entries()` instead.

Solution for `FormData.entries()` (this worked for me):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49556416/3806701

Basically, import this poly-fill:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/formdata-polyfill"></script>
```

Then you can iterate `FormData` as follows:

```
var formDataEntries = (<any>formData).entries(), formDataEntry = formDataEntries.next(), pair;
while (!formDataEntry.done) {
    pair = formDataEntry.value;
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    formDataEntry = formDataEntries.next();
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me. i still get the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'`

Comment: If you are struggling to solve this issue in 2020 (using React), please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079188/create-react-app-not-working-in-ie11-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method

Comment: Changing es7 to es worked for me: import 'core-js/es/object'; in the Polyfills file.

Comment: you should have both es6 and es7 object imported `import 'core-js/es6/object'` & `import 'core-js/es7/object'`

Answer (score 23):

If you're in an Angular App please add this line to your polyfills.ts file

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
```

It will import all the new methods on Object, including entries

[image]

Comment: This worked when upgrading from Angular 6 to Angular 8.  Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

By importing

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
```

if you are getting error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/object'

then Change all "es6" and "es7" to "es" in your imports.

```
import 'core-js/es/object';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below code in my polyfills.ts and  it worked for me.

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/array';

if (!Object.entries)
  { Object.entries = function(obj)
        { 
          var ownProps = Object.keys(obj),
          i = ownProps.length,
          resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array while (i--) 
          resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]]; 
          return resArray; 
        }; 
  }
```