# Object doesn't support this property or method 'entries' (polyfill not working in edge)

Tags: javascript, polyfills, babel-polyfill

I have the same issue as this [Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446062/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-entries) and I installed the polyfill as one of the first scripts to run on my app.

**This is the JS that has error**

```
const formdata = new FormData(form);
for (var value of formdata.entries()) {
   console.log(value); 
}
```

**Here Is the polyfill I am trying**

```
if (!Object.entries) { 
    //this does not run on Edge. So Object.entries must exist
    Object.entries = function( obj ){
        var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
            i = ownProps.length,
            resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
        while (i--)
          resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

        return resArray;
    };
}
```

> The script as it is above does not run on Edge. So `Object.entries` must exist. So I tried the following.

```
Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
};
```

> Now I know for sure that the script is on the page. but when I use `Object.entries` the error comes before the polyfill was used

How come the error runs instead of the polyfill on edge despite it definitely being on the page?

Comment: [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is not the same as [`FormData.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries). Edge [does not support `FormData.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: `Object.entries` is a static method of the `Object` object, not an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

This Q&A you linked to, which told you to use an `Object.entries` polyfill to supply an `entries` method on `FormData` instances, is absolutely incorrect. The polyfill you've supplied for `Object.entries` adds an `entries` method to the `Object` constructor object: that is, you may safely use the literal expression `Object.entries(something)` to call the method `entries` on the object `Object`. `Object.entries` is a different function and does a different operation from the `entries` method that exists on `FormData` instances.

Instead, you need a polyfill for `Formdata.prototype.entries`. One option is available at https://github.com/github/form-data-entries, though it achieves its goal by having you write `formDataEntries(myForm)` instead of `new FormData(myform).entries()`. This is *not* a proper polyfill (they call it a "ponyfill"), since it does not add an `entries` method to `FormData` but instead supplies an entirely new function that does the same thing.