# forEach not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

```
var formd = new FormData(form);
    formd.forEach(function(value, key){
        data[key] = value;
});
```

How can I make this forEach function to work in Edge by replacing it with for loop?

Comment: Are you sure this works in chrome?

Comment: please add `FormData`. it looks like you return an instance of the function which is not an array. this is not only a problem of IE, but of language specification, which requires an array.

Comment: @Nina Scholz: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: @Lain, thank you, didn't know. `FormData` returns an instance, as thought without `forEach` method.

Comment: @Nina Scholz: Yes, depends on the browser. In Chrome and Firefox it does, in Edge it does not.

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal It doesn't work only in Edge and IE

Comment: @Laken-JS: As you can see in my link Edge aswell as IE do not have iteration support with `FormData`. So you are right - it does and will not work like this. Read thise one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938955/iterating-through-formdata-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

Would mark it as duplicate if I could (maybe someone else can).
IE11 and Edge do not support iteration in `FormData`. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData

One needs a polyfill to correct it.
Here is a way to fix it:
[Iterating through FormData in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938955/iterating-through-formdata-in-ie)