# Issues with FormData Being Null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I'm seeming to have an issue with FormData being null. I'm trying to upload files and JSON in a single POST request. I've tried a variety of things, but nothing has seemed to work. I'm wondering if I've messed something basic up here, but I can't seem to find anything. Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
<form id="uploadCSVWithData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-info">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Upload CSV File <input type="file" name="csvUploadFile" class="upload" />
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="distName" id="distName"></br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="columnNames" id="columnNames"></br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="columnPrices" id="columnPrices"></br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="columnCases" id="columnCases"></br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="columnIds" id="columnIds">
</form>
```

And Javascript:

```
event.preventDefault();
var prices = $("#columnPrices").val();
var id = $("#columnIds").val();
var names = $("#columnNames").val();
var distName = $("#distName").val();
var cases = $("#columnCases").val();
var json = {
    columnPrices: prices,
    columnIds: id,
    columnNames: names,
    columnDistName: distName,
    columnCases: cases
}
var data = new FormData($("#uploadCSVWithData"));

console.log("Data is " + JSON.stringify(data))
$(this).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true">');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{removed}',
    data: {
        json: json,
        formData: data
    },
    success: function(done) {
        $("#submitCSVForUpload").html("Submit");
        $("#uploadFromCSVModal").modal('hide');
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FormData` can't be inspected with `console.log` without [iterating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries).

Here is an article on [how to inspect `FormData`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

If you want to `console.log` your `FormData` object before doing the ajax post request, you can do something like this (I'm using the example from the [source docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) with your code):

```js
var form = $('#uploadCSVWithData')[0];
var data = new FormData(form);

// Display the key/value pairs
for(var pair of data.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
}
```

Comment: Cool - glad it helped.

Comment: It can. With the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you can do something like this: `console.log(...data);`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have same problem and I think know the solution after I read this documentation from  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

I fix it with this way:

```javascript
var formData = new FormData();
// After instantiate the object we should use append method
// And append more data as you needed with this way:

formData.append('prices', $("#columnPrices").val());
formData.append('id', $("#columnIds").val());
formData.append('file', $("#uploadCSVWithData");

$(this).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true">');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{removed}',
    data: formData,
    success: function(done) {
        $("#submitCSVForUpload").html("Submit");
        $("#uploadFromCSVModal").modal('hide');
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

I hope it can help you :D