# Javascript formdata is empty when trying to append values in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

following is my code when i do **`console.log(formData);`**  its empty. Cannot see a reason for it to fail down.

```
$("#add_meal_item").on('click', '#save_meal_item', function () {
                var meal_name = $("#add_meal_item_form").find('#meal_name').val();
                var meal_type = $("#add_meal_item_form").find('#meal_type').val();
                var logoImg = $("#add_meal_item_form").find('#meal_image').get(0).files[0];
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('logo', logoImg);
                formData.append('meal_type', meal_type);
                formData.append('meal_name', meal_name);
                console.log(formData);
                var ajax_url = baseurl + '/save_meal_item';
                $.ajax({
                    url: ajax_url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {

                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: A `FormData` instance is not like a normal object (if it were you could just use one), logging it to the console does not display it's contents. Are you not seeing the data server-side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

Comment: Do   formData.forEach(function(k,v){
                console.log(k,v)
                })

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get elements values first and then append them to formData, Like this:

```
var meal_name = $("#add_meal_item_form").find('#meal_name').val();
formData.append('meal_name ', meal_name );
```

And to show all formData keys and values you have to use [FormData.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) method :

```
for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
     console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
}
```

Comment: regardless its still the same, i will edit my question to ease out with `val()`

Answer (score 2):

`FormData.append()` doesn't create enumerable properties for `formData`, you need to use the iterator from [FormData.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) to iterate the values.

**Demo**

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('logo', "11");
formData.append('meal_type', "22");
formData.append('meal_name', "33");

console.log(Object.keys(formData)); //[]
console.log(JSON.stringify(formData)); //{}

//use iterator
var formEntries = formData.entries();
//console.log(formEntries.next().value); 
//console.log(formEntries.next().value); 
//console.log(formEntries.next().value); 

//or simply use Array.from
var formEntries = Array.from(formData.entries());
console.log("formEntries " , formEntries);
```