# Formdata is blank at the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, multipartform-data, form-data

I pass image data by appending with formdata in reactjs

This is the handler for this

```
handleUserImage(e) {
    const input = e.target
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = (r) => {
        const formdata = new FormData()
        formdata.append('photos', input.files[0])
        formdata.append('fileName', input.files[0].name)
        this.props.uploadImage({ image: formdata })
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0])
    }
  }
```

and when I console it to backend it looks like blank object

```
{ image: {} }
```

Then how can I pass formdata and upload the image

**Edit** : Upload image api call

```
export const uploadImage = (data) => {
  console.log(data)
  return fetch(`http://hostName:3001/town/image`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: data
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json()
  })
  .then((payload) => {
    console.log(payload)
    return payload
  }).catch((error) => {
   throw error
  })
}
```

Comment: What does your `this.props.uploadImage` look like?

Comment: @Tholle Sorry for the late reply. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I console it to backend it looks like blank object

[This is normal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

> ```
>  headers: {
>        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
>  },
> ```

Multipart form data MIME types need to have a parameter to describe the boundary marker (so parsers know where one field ends and the next begins).

Yours is missing it. What's more, there is no way for you to know what it will be.

**Don't** override the Content-Type header, allow `fetch` to generate it from the `FormData` object. Remove the code I quoted entirely.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much!!! But your explanation is gone above my level :-(

Answer (score 1):

Why use FileReader, upload it as base64 and append file name separately?

you can just do

```
handleUserImage (evt) {
  const file = evt.target.files[0]
  if (file) {
    const formdata = new FormData()
    formdata.append('photos', file)
    this.props.uploadImage({ image: formdata })
  }
}
```

- You save a few bytes,
- avoid unnecessary decode & encode calculations
- runs faster
- saves ~3x bandwidth

---

**FormData.append(name, value, filename)**

**name**
The name of the field whose data is contained in value.
**value**
The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File).
**filename** Optional
The filename reported to the server (a USVString), when a Blob or File is passed as the second parameter. The default filename for Blob objects is "blob". The default filename for File objects is the file's filename.

-- [MDN - FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)