# formdata in angular 5 showing empty when console.log()

Tags: angular, angular5

In Angular 5 `html`, I did the following and press the submit button. Here, in the `.ts` file, I want to append custom value and then want to console/print the value of the submitted form.

```
<form method="post" (ngSubmit)="signupFrm.form.valid && onSubmit(signupFrm)" #signupFrm="ngForm">
...
...
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the `.ts` file, I wrote:

```
import { NgForm }   from '@angular/forms';
....
....
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
  console.log(form.value);
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('mycustom', "custom");
  for(let eachField in form.value)
  {
    formData.append(eachField,form.value[eachField]);
  }
  console.log(formData);
}
```

I see the console showing empty formData. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the console with this method.

```
console.log(formData.getAll('mycustom'));
```

Also there are other methods on **FormData**:

[image]

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara check out this topic and first answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata