# FormData.append() doesn't work with files

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, form-data

I try to append a `File` object to a `FormData` object in JavaScript, but it doesn't work and only a empty object is added. If I try to append a key/value it works fine.

There is no error / warning message in the console. I activated all channels.

I try out examples from the web and from the MDN. But nothing helps. I don't understand why? Is file access blocked by security reasons?

I'm use Firefox 64.0 or Chrome 71.0. Currently the example doesn't contain any client-server communication. But I tried it in two ways: as a local file and a page loaded from a web server.

The background of my question is, I would like to upload files with XmlHttpRequest in a script to a server.

**Console**

```
File(234321) {name: "refresh2.gpx", lastModified: 1503041677210,
              lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 18 2017 09:34:37 GMT+0200 (...),
              webkitRelativePath: "", size: 234321, …}

{"key":"value","userfile":{}}
```

**HTML body**

```
<body>
<form id="file-form" action="handler.php" method="POST">
  <input type="file" id="file-select" />
  <button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload</button>
</form>
</body>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
document.getElementById('file-form').onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected files from the input.
    var files = document.getElementById('file-select').files;

    // Create a new FormData object.
    var formData = new FormData();
    console.log(files[0]);
    formData.append("key", "value");
    formData.append("userfile", files[0]);

    // dump formData object
    var object = {};
    formData.forEach(function(value, key){
        object[key] = value;
    });
    var json = JSON.stringify(object);
    console.log(json);

    // xmlhttprequest part comes here....
}
</script>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help

CachingFoX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FormData` has the file but it not shown because JSON.stringify will log the file as an empty obj.

Please use this to log all your form data

```
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helps me a lot.