# How to resolve problem with formData() to send with axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, form-data

I need to register the user. I need to send `body` --> `form Data`. For some reason, I can't see my information after appending to formData.

Please check my code, what is wrong

This is console.log with formData, it's empty after submit. I don't know why?
[image]

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { AUTH } from './actionTypes'
const session_url = 'http://flowrspot-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/register'

export const registerUser = (data) => {
  console.log('register action', data)
  return dispatch => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('first_name', data.first_name);
    formData.append('last_name', data.last_name);
    formData.append('date_of_birth', '11/09/1993');
    formData.append('email', data.emailRegister);
    formData.append('password', data.passwordRegister);
    console.log('bodyFormDate', formData)
    axios.post(session_url, formData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('dsada', response)
        dispatch({
          type: AUTH.REGISTER_USER,
          payload: response.data
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('err', error)
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata

Answer (score 0):

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('key1', 'value1');
    formData.append('key2', 'value2');

    // Display the key/value pairs
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
    }
```

was taken here: [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)