# Can't populate FormData object

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

Trying to figure out FormData, but can't populate it. Other similar questions were because of lacking `name` attribute to `form` elements, but it seems to not be the case there.

HTML code:

```
<form class="testForm" action="/database" method="put">
            <input type="text" name="bar" value="foo">
</form>
<button type="button" class="testButt" name="testButt">click me!</button>
```

JS code:

```
const testButt = document.querySelector('.testButt');
const testForm = document.querySelector(".testForm");

putDataTest = function(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData(testForm);
    console.log(formData);      // using existing form as a source, returns an empty formData object;
    formData.append("foo", "bar");
    console.log(formData);      // populating the object explicitly, still empty formData object;
    xhr.open('PUT', '/database');
    xhr.send(formData);         // server sees req.body as empty
}

testButt.addEventListener("click", putDataTest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(document.forms[0].bar.value); // gets value from textbox.
```

Create your own form data:

```
var formData = new FormData();     // this is a *new* FormData object.
formData.append('foo', 'bar');
console.log(formData.get('foo'));
```

Comment: Using `get` method seems to be working correctly. Getting data from the request should be another question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The data is actually there, but you can't access the values directly by outputting the object with `console.log(formData)`. See [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata). You can also output specific values by using the [get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) method.

**Here's an example:**

```js
const testButt = document.querySelector('.testButt');
const testForm = document.querySelector(".testForm");

putDataTest = function() {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var formData = new FormData(testForm);
  formData.append("new", "foo");
  console.log(formData.get('new'));
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }
  xhr.open('PUT', '/database');
  xhr.send(formData); // server sees req.body as empty
}

testButt.addEventListener("click", putDataTest);
```

```html
<form class="testForm" action="/database" method="put">
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
  <input type="text" name="bar" value="foo">
</form>
<button type="button" class="testButt" name="testButt">click me!</button>
```