# Play Framework File Upload Not Working (React/Scala)

Tags: reactjs, scala, session, file-upload, playframework

I am attempting to upload a file from a React frontend to a Scala/Play Framework backend and it is not working.

So I have a button that uploads a file and calls `handleUpload`:

```
handleUpload=()=>{
    if(this.state.file!=null){
      console.log('value of this.state.file: ', this.state.file)
      var dataSend = new FormData();
      dataSend.append('file_upload', this.state.file); 
      console.log('value of dataSend before send: ', dataSend);
      this.setState({lastCommand: 'file_upload'}, ()=>{
        this.props.sendRequest({
          url: "http://localhost:9000/upload",
          method: "post",
          multipart: true,
          data:{
            payload:{
              data: dataSend
            }
          }
        });
      })
    }
  }
```

`this.props.sendRequest` is in my actions (Redux) and is the following:

```
export const request = payload => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log("value of payload in actions request: ", payload)
    var config = {}
    if (payload.method=="post"||payload.method=="patch"){
      config = {
        url:    payload.url,
        method: payload.method,
        withCredentials: true,
        data:   payload.data,
      }
      if('multipart' in payload && payload.multipart){
        config.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
      }
    }else if (payload.method=='get'){
      config = {
        url:    payload.url,
        method: payload.method,
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    }

    console.log('value of config before send in actions/request: ', config);

    axios(config)
    .then(response=>{
      return dispatch({
        val: response,
        type: (payload.method=="post"||payload.method=="patch")?"POST_RETURN_SUCCESSFUL":"GET_RETURN_SUCCESSFUL", 
        sentID: ('sentID' in payload)?payload.sentID:null
      })
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log('there was an error in request return in actions', error);
      return dispatch({
        val: error,
        type: (payload.method=="post"||payload.method=="patch")?"POST_RETURN_ERROR":"GET_RETURN_ERROR",
        sentID: ('sentID' in payload)?payload.sentID:null
      })
    });
  };
}
```

Here is the value of the config as console logged above:

```
value of config before send in actions/request:  
{…}
​
data: {…}
​​
payload: {…}
​​​
data: FormData {  }
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: {…}
​​
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
method: "post"
​
url: "http://localhost:9000/upload"
​
withCredentials: true
```

Note that while it appears that the form data is empty this is an artifact of the inability of the web console to display it ([How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata))

This should be hitting the following route in my play framework (as defined in my `config/routes` file):

```
+nocsrf
POST    /upload        controllers.PostController.admin_upload
```

where `+nocsrf` is simply a handler to prevent cross site request forgery.

**NOTE**: I am sending to the url *"http://localhost:9000/upload"* on the frontend.

My upload function `controllers.PostController.admin_upload` is a simple `hello_there`

```
def admin_upload[T]:Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {request: Request
  [AnyContent] => Future { 
      println("****************************")
      println("inside admin_upload")
      println("****************************")
      var responseVal = new Response().standard_response("/admin/patch", "DUMMY - STILL WORKING ON ROUTE")
      Ok(responseVal)
    }(ec)
  }
```

I get no console logging on the backend, and I get a `400 NOT FOUND` error on the frontend.

Here is my network request headers:

```
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 23
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:3000/admin
Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=SUPERDOOPERSECRETDAWG
```

and response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Vary: Origin
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: master-only
Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2019 17:08:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1170
```

I am totally lost, this should work.

What is broken?

**EDIT:**

If I drop the `Content-Type` header on the axios request and console out the result I *do* get inside the `admin_upload` function but the request body is of course empty because I haven't sent a form. So I've narrowed the problem to "how do I send the correct content-type flag to play framework?"

```
****************************
inside admin_upload
****************************
value of request.body: 
AnyContentAsJson({"payload":{"data":{}}})
request.body.asMultipartFormData
None
```

**EDIT EDIT:**

Even the most simple example as shown from here: *https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaFileUpload*

Doe not appear to work.

```
  def admin_upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    println("****************************")
    println("inside admin_upload")
    println("****************************")
    println(request.body)
    var responseVal = new Response().standard_response("/admin/patch", "DUMMY - STILL WORKING ON ROUTE")
    Ok(responseVal)
  }
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT:**

OK - this *does* work in Insomnia, I had it configured incorrectly. This means that the issue is that **axios** is not working correctly, I'll send a bug report to them.

[image: axios is borked]

Comment: Have you tried to test upload manually? using cURL? Where is the request URI/path in the traces ?

Comment: So, I am testing manually now - I'm using insomnia (like postman). Ditching the Content-Type header works but I don't know yet if that will allow me to send the form data. Something is weird. (I get `For request 'POST /upload' [Missing boundary header]` if I use Content-Type).

Comment: when you print the request headers could you show the route you are hitting. are you hitting the correct route?

Comment: Sorry - see above edit. I think play framework is not seeing `Content-Type` header correctly.

Comment: Play is using content type properly

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make a cut out in my request handler and use `fetch` instead of `axios` for file uploads. Like this:

```
export const request = payload => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log("value of payload in actions request: ", payload)
    var config = {}
    if('multipart' in payload && payload.multipart){
      config = {
        method: "POST",
        body: payload.data
      }
      fetch("http://localhost:9000/upload", config)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log("inside success in fetch and value of response: ", response)
        return dispatch({
          val: response,
          type: "POST_RETURN_SUCCESSFUL"
        })
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log('there was an error in request return in actions', error);
        return dispatch({
          val: error,
          type: "POST_RETURN_ERROR"
        })
      });
    }else{
      if (payload.method=="post"||payload.method=="patch"){
        config = {
          url:    payload.url,
          method: payload.method,
          withCredentials: true,
          data:   payload.data,
        }
      }else if (payload.method=='get'){
        config = {
          url:    payload.url,
          method: payload.method,
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      }
      console.log('value of config before send in actions/request: ', config);

      axios(config)
      .then(response=>{
        return dispatch({
          val: response,
          type: (payload.method=="post"||payload.method=="patch")?"POST_RETURN_SUCCESSFUL":"GET_RETURN_SUCCESSFUL", 
          sentID: ('sentID' in payload)?payload.sentID:null
        })
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log('there was an error in request return in actions', error);
        return dispatch({
          val: error,
          type: (payload.method=="post"||payload.method=="patch")?"POST_RETURN_ERROR":"GET_RETURN_ERROR",
          sentID: ('sentID' in payload)?payload.sentID:null
        })
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Axios has problems an issue with file uploads. See here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318

The workaround then is to use fetch.