# FormData append File does not work Angular

Tags: angular, form-data

I'm using FormData to send image to PHP API. When I use this code it does not work:

HTML Code :

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" />
<button pButton (click)="onUpload()" label="UPLOAD"></button>
```

TS Code :

```
onFileSelected(event) {
    this.uploadFile = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.uploadFile);
}

onUpload() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('myfile', this.uploadFile, this.uploadFile.name);
    console.log(formData);
}
```

When `console.log(this.uploadFile)` i get :
[image]

and `console.log(formData)` i get :

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues with your code. Trying to `console.log` formdata will always give an empty object.

To display your filedata change your console.log to

```
console.log(formdata.getAll('myfile'));
```

The above function will return an array with your file object blob.

You can also refer to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for all the other formData functions