# send file and data to server with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am using ReactJs and wanna send data to Laravel API with Axios.

I try

```js
export const send = (data, File) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('media', File);
  try {
    PostRequest.post('/post', { formData, data })
      .then(r => console.log(r.data))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

and I call **send** like this :

```js
let data = {
  mobile: mobile,
  email: emailAddress,
  userName: userName,
  password: password,
  firstName: firstName,
  lastName: lastName,
  website: website,
  bio: bio,
  date: selectedDay,
  code: code,
};
console.log(profile);
console.log(data);
send(data, profile);
```

the log

[image: log data]

but form data is null in the response

[image: form data]

I set the header like this :

```js
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  "Accept":"application/json"
}
```

also I try

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('media', profile);
let data = {
  mobile: mobile,
  email: emailAddress,
  userName: userName,
  password: password,
  firstName: firstName,
  lastName: lastName,
  website: website,
  bio: bio,
  date: selectedDay,
  code: code,
  media: formData,
};
send(data);
```

but the media is null

Comment: In your first attempt, what is the type of the `File` variable? .append() is expecting instanceof Blob/File, and I can't tell if you're using the class called https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File or forgot to call it or if it already is it.

Comment: @JonathanRosa the File set by input file like : const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        setProfile(e.target.files[0]);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your implementation at all. You can't log the `formData` in the console and expect to see its entities as the other objects.

So, the empty `formData` on the console is proper behavior. if you really want to inspect your `formData`, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata).

thus, your `send` method is working properly and sending the correct data to the server.

##### Optional

On the server, you need to get the `formData` and parse it, so it must be implemented on the server-side. since you need to get the body request in `formData`, you could **append** all your `data` in the whitin a `formData` and send a single `formData`, but its depened on the backend implementation, if you  can change the server-side, I engourage you to appnend all your data in the `formData` and then send it.

Answer (score 1):

you can have an uploader like this , which will work with ;)

```
 const Uploader = ({ url, updateData }) => {
function handleUpload(e) {
if (e.target.files[0]) {
  console.log(e.target.files);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("config", e.target.files[0], e.target.files[0].name);
  console.log(formData);
  axios.post(url, formData).then(res => {
    updateData(res);
  });
}
}
return (
<label>
  <div className={styles.uploaderBtn}>
    <input
      type="file"
      style={{ display: "none" }}
      onChange={e => {
        handleUpload(e);
      }}></input>
    <img src={Upload} alt="" />
  </div>
</label>
);
};
```

Comment: I wanna send file and other data in my code if I send just file without data it is ok but when I add other data like username and ... do not work

Comment: you must append all your data parameters to your formdata either , and then in the backend read it from formdata