# React sending empty object instead of formData to API

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I did the following request with JS and it worked. Now trying to adapt in for react and getting an empty object being posted. Below just bits of code, but basically I am generating pdf and aiming to send it to backend:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
const blob = doc.output('blob');
const email = formData.emailRequired;

const formDataToSend = new FormData();
formDataToSend.append('email', email);
formDataToSend.append('file', blob);
console.log(formDataToSend)

fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/contract',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      data: formDataToSend,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
});
```

Unfortunatelly on submit I get FormData {} - so it's an empty object. Why?

Comment: Where are you seeing empty at the frontend or backend? And what is this `formData `?

Comment: Frontend, but it also doesn't arrive at the backend. FormData is a JS Object: const formDataToSend = new FormData();

Comment: So, you might be incorrectly passing the form data or appending it.

Comment: Exactly the same code worked in vanilla js, and I checkt syntax for react is same. That it's not appending is clear, questions is why :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormData is not an empty object, it is displayed like this in the console.

If you want to display all entries, then use this approach

```
console.log([...formDataToSend.entries()])
```

Related question [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17066875/14207720)