# couldn't update the formData

Tags: reactjs, form-data

My goal is to send the uploaded image to the backend, but after appending it to formData, the formData looks empty.
But logging the file shows there is an image in the state.

**Code:**

```
function UpdateProfile() {
    const [file, setFile]: any = useState(null);
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        console.log(file);
        formData.append("profile", "file");
        console.log("formData", formData);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Modal>
                    <ModalBody pb={6}>
                        <FormControl>
                            <FormLabel>Profile Picture</FormLabel>
                            <Input
                                name="profile"
                                type="file"
                                onChange={(e: any) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                            />
                        </FormControl>
                    </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}
```

The above `console.log(file)` logs,

```
File {name: 'burger 2.png', lastModified: 1658142356471, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 18 2022 16:35:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 156243, …}
```

But logging formData,
`formData {}` its empty.

CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-chatelet-bw8lh4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `FormData` instances do not serialise to the console. Why are you logging it anyway?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass form dom to form data

until you pass **handleSubmit(e);** default event to handle you cant't get form data
and then pass **e.target** dom to form data to get  new FormData(e.target);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

```
    function UpdateProfile() {
        const [file, setFile]: any = useState(null);
        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            const formData = new FormData(e.target);
            console.log(file);
            formData.append("profile", "file");
            console.log("formData", formData);
        };
    
        return (
            <>

<form onSubmit={()=>{handleSubmit(e);}}>
                <Modal>
                        <ModalBody pb={6}>
                            <FormControl>
                                <FormLabel>Profile Picture</FormLabel>
                                <Input
                                    name="profile"
                                    type="file"
                                    onChange={(e: any) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                                />
                            </FormControl>
                        </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            </>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still the same issue, file is in the state, but formData seems empty

Comment: do you have any desk ?

Comment: Codesandbox link :  https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-chatelet-bw8lh4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The `FormData` constructor does not require the `form` parameter

Answer (score 0):

I think accessing the FormData instance doesn't work cause it supposed to be private properties. try FormData methods like .get() and .has() to access data inside it.