# Getting an empty object when i pass my file to formData

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, form-data

i have a project and i am trying to send an image to the API. the curl for API endPoint is as follows:

```
curl --location 'https://do-rider.cheetay.pk/alerts/image' \
--header 'Authorization: Token a24ffbda2317e9b41ce227856e0603b7c7666ccc ' \
--form 'image=@"/home/abdul/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot from 2023-04-01 02-37-29.png"'
```

now this API will accept an image. now i am taking an image from user like this:

```
<input
          type="file"
          name="image"
          onChange={event => {
            handleImageChange(event);
            setFieldValue("image", event.currentTarget.files[0]);
          }}
        />
```

and then i am trying to pass it to formData as i want to convert the image into the content type that is needed by the API.

```
const handleImageChange = event => {
    const file = event.currentTarget.files[0];
    setSelectedImage(file);
    console.log("file", file);
    debugger;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", file);
    console.log("formData", formData);
    debugger;
    sendImageAttempt(formData); // Call sendImageAttempt function with FormData object
  };
```

here you can see when i am consoling file i am getting the input file of image this is what it looks like in console:

```
file {name: 'Mind map.png', lastModified: 1684153465349, lastModifiedDate: Mon May 15 2023 17:24:25 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 315013, …}
```

but when i am passing it to formData and trying to console the formData it is an empty object like this :

```
formData FormData {}
```

can you tell me the problem.

this my action and when i am calling from saga :

```
export const sendImageAttempt = data => ({
  type: types.SEND_IMAGE_ATTEMPT,
  data
});
```

my saga middleware:

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { actions } from "../../actions/alerts";
import { sendImageAlertAPI } from "../../api/alerts";
import { logger } from "../../utils";

export function* sendImageAttemptSaga({ data }) {
  try {
    console.log("data for api", data);
    debugger;
    const resp = yield call(sendImageAlertAPI, data); // Send the data directly to the API
    debugger;
    if (resp) {
      yield put(actions.sendImageSuccess(resp));
      toast.success("Alert sent");
    } else {
      yield put(actions.sendImageFailure(""));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
    yield put(actions.sendImageFailure(error));
    toast.error(error.toString());
  }
}
```

. and this is my API call:

```
export const sendImageAlertAPI = data => {
  console.log("data in apicaller", data);
  debugger;
  apiCaller({
    method: REQUEST_TYPES.POST,
    url: ENDPOINTS.SEND_IMAGE,
    contentType: "multipart/form-data",
    data
  });
};
```

Comment: You can't directly console.log a formData to view appended items, use the method answered in this question to do so : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata