# Send All FormControls + Uploaded File to API

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to send an uploaded file, along with several other FormControls.

```js
profilePictureFile?: File;

submit(): void {
  if (this.form.valid) {
    // Create FormData
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(this.form.getRawValue()).forEach((controlName: string): void => {
      const control = this.form.get(controlName);
      formData.append(controlName, control?.value);
      console.log(`name = ${controlName}, value = ${control?.value}`); // <-- has data
    });
    console.log(this.profilePictureFile, 'file'); // <-- has data
    if (this.profilePictureFile) {
      formData.append('profilePictureFile', this.profilePictureFile);
    }
    console.log(formData); // <-- empty FormData
  }
}

onFileChange($event: any) {
  this.profilePictureFile = $event.target.files[0];
}
```

```html
<img (click)="uploadProfileImage.click()" src="../assets/img/user-128.png">
<input (change)="onFileChange($event)" hidden accept="image/*" #uploadProfileImage type="file" formControlName="profilePicture">
```

My goal is to send `formData` (all FormControls + uploaded file) to the API, but `formData` is empty. However, `formData.getAll('profilePictureFile')` returns all data from that file. How can I send entire `formData`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673708/10480323