# Can't build a FormData object out of existing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to build a FormData object out of a form on my page. I'm getting the form element like this:

```
var form = document.forms['upload_form'];
```

And then I'm building the FormData object like this:

```
var fd = new FormData(form);
```

Since you cannot log values in a FormData object (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752188/formdata-appendkey-value-is-not-working)), I'm sending the formdata to '/' just so I can see its contents in my Network Inspector. The contents of the request payload are simply:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKAgAjii8IMLyJFcB--
```

and nothing else! If I manually append a value to the form like this:

```
fd.append("username", "Groucho");
```

it works:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZikgEBo7sTzvlndC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

Groucho
```

I've also tried selecting the form element in other ways, such as with jQuery:

```
var form = $(".upload_form");
var fd = new FormData(form[0]);
```

No matter how I select the form element, the form variable certainly does have the form in it (it's not null or empty), but constructing the FormData object with it as a parameter just does not seem to work. Can anyone help?

**PS** I'm using Chrome 31.0.1650.57. I've also tried this in Safari 7.0 with the same results.

**Another thing**: The inputs in this form are nested inside a number of divs. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Are you constructing your _FormData_ after the form exists **and** has been filled in? Does the form actually submit anything if you do it in _pure HTML_?

Comment: Yes, I am constructing the FormData after the form exists and has been filled in. The form does not submit anything in pure HTML, since this is a JavaScript-only web app, and I only wish to submit the form with AJAX. Therefore, the form does not have an action or a method, or a submit input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happening because I didn't have `name` attributes set on my inputs. Apparently, `new FormData()` and `$.serialize()` will ignore any inputs without names.