# Check if formdata object key exists

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, forms, jquery-ui

Is it possible to run a check on a key for the formdata object? I would like to know if a key has already been assigned a value.

tried something like this with negative results

```
data=new FormData();
if(!data.key)
data.append(key,somevalue);
```

addition question is the nature of a double assignment to rewrite the original value?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752188/formdata-appendkey-value-is-not-working

Comment: @tony Ok i can appreciate what the browser platform is trying to do with security I have an idea of what  would be a suitable work around based off of your link. Why not why not give an example of putting it in a wrapper object that records the kv pairs and I'll accept it as an answer for reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are changing and nowadays you can check if key exits using [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) function.

**Original answer**

As we already discussed in comments, browser hides data which is stored in `FormData` object due to security reasons. There is one workaround which helps to preview its data in developer console which is described here: [FormData.append("key", "value") is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752188/formdata-appendkey-value-is-not-working)

The only way to have access to such data in code is to use own wrapping object, which supports appending data, getting values and converting to `FormData`. It could be an object like this:

```
function FormDataUnsafe() {
    this.dict = {};
};

FormDataUnsafe.prototype.append = function(key, value) {
    this.dict[key] = value;
};

FormDataUnsafe.prototype.contains = function(key) {
    return this.dict.hasOwnProperty(key);
};

FormDataUnsafe.prototype.getValue = function(key) {
    return this.dict[key];
};

FormDataUnsafe.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    for(var key in this.dict) {
        if (this.dict.hasOwnProperty(key))
            fd.append(key, this.dict[key]);
    }

    return fd;
};

FormDataUnsafe.prototype.safe = function() {
    return this.valueOf();
};
```

Usage:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
xhr.send(data.safe());  // convertion here
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bP9WD/)

Comment: for a little more insight for those in the same situation. the recommended solution is to record what you put in in some form or other(answer does that in the form of a wrapping object). and use that reference to say what you already put in hence if the key already exists

Comment: At least, can I check if `formdata` object has a file inside?

Comment: Could you give some details about "browser  hides data which is stored in FormData object due to security reasons." even if a link is preferred.

Comment: @PageYe this answer is very old and many things changed since that time, so it seems now it is not a security issue anymore.

Comment: @Tony I just want to know the reason why should browser hides data instead of showing the properties directly?