# FormData empty when constructing with element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

Trying to construct a new `FormData` object to send as part of an AJAX request, however constructing the object with a jQuery selected object remains empty.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not empty, you just [can't see it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7752337/1713660)

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) is created only for sending keyed data, not fot retrieving it

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Problem is when I used `submit` to send the form, I recieved data with `'image'` as the key. When I POST with jquery and include the `new FormData(...)` object as data, I don't get that key.

Comment: @Aesthete did you try to _set the right options_: `processData: false` and `contentType: false` as mentioned in last example in [article I provided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object) in my answer?

Comment: Yep, had all those values setup. I've gone with another solution, but your answer is still correct. Now I know why it appears empty.

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox you can use this:[code]
      for (var pair of frmData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
      }[/code]