# Append var to FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using CKEditor as a WYSIWYG editor for an internal email system that I'm building, which requires me to get the data from from the textarea input like this:

```
var message = CKEDITOR.instances.messageArea.getData();
```

I am also allowing users to send attachments and I am sending the files to the server via the HTML5 FormData.

```
//create form variable
var form = $('#sendIndividualEmail')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

I have tried to append the the message variable to the formData, but it seems that formData only allows form fields to be appended.

Is there alternative way to append a var to FormData if it isn't a form field?  If not, is there another way to get the message variable to the server with the formData?

ajax code:

```
request = $.ajax({
            url: baseURL+'/sendIndividualMessage',
            type: "post",
            data: formData,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            dataType: json,
            contentType: false, //required for formData
            cache: false,
            processData: false, //require for formData
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append data to a FormData like that :

```
formData.append('message', message);
```

It doesn't need to be a form field.
To debug FormData, you have to post the data.

[MDN FormData.append() Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Have a look here : [FormData.append("key", "value") is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752188/formdata-appendkey-value-is-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I appreciate it.  I thought that only providing the ability to append in form fields was a little limiting.