# Append simple file to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm uploading the formData and somehow I'm getting a empty file on the headers using this

```
 var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('creationForm'));
 console.log(file);
 formData.append("fileUpload", file);
```

It just doesn't work when i do the drag and drop. So how do I append the file to the actual input that is on the creationForm?

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" class="hide"/>
```

Comment: If I do `$('#fileUpload').val(file);` it give me Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: Some Security Reason. Look for [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: so how can i do this? console.log of the file has the file there and when I append it to the formData i get a file with size 0??

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: I assume you can use the files property:  **file.files[0]**

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand the drag and drop, in IE can't drag n drop to a input type file, for example, but i think that [this](http://[1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752188/formdata-appendkey-value-is-not-working) answer can help.